# How does one get compiler and linker flags in an intel mkl installation?

Tags: intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I just installed intel oneAPI base kit along with oneHPC kit just to be able to use its matrix operation functions. However, the examples directory inside the directory "intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/" does not contain make files as has been mentioned in its developer guide. The functions I need are dgetrf and dgetri.

Comment: You do not need any Makefile, follow https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-link-line-advisor.html I do not understand which mention do you mean. Can you quote it?

Comment: This is where it says the examples directory contains the make files necessary to generate linker and compiler flags. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-guide-linux/2023-0/using-code-examples.html

Comment: On following the instructions given in the link shared by you, I got the following results. For compiler options                                                                                          -I${MKLROOT}/include/intel64/ilp64 -i8  -I"${MKLROOT}/include"

Comment: For link line,  ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_ilp64.a -Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm -ldl

Comment: So, how do I go about compiling my code? ifort -I${MKLROOT}/include/intel64/ilp64 -i8 -I"${MKLROOT}/include"  myfile.f90  ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_ilp64.a -Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm -ldl

Comment: Is the above command correct?

Comment: The link you show speaks about a makefile to build their examples, not tu build your code.

Comment: Just follow the Advisor and think about each coice you are being asked. If you need an explanation, you can ask. But you almost surely do not want ilp64. Unless you use some special options, your integers are 32 bit, not 64 bit.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. And about the command format, is the line in my question about the format correct?

Comment: ifort -I-I${MKLROOT}/include/ia32/ -I"${MKLROOT}/include"DFT_grafted.f90   ${MKLROOT}/lib/ia32/libmkl_lapack95.a -Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/ia32/libmkl_intel.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/ia32/libmkl_sequential.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm -ldl
On using the above command, I am getting the following error message:

Comment: ld: /home/username/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.1.0/linux/bin/intel64/../../compiler/lib/intel64_lin/for_main.o: in function `main':
for_main.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `MAIN__'

Comment: We have several questions and answers about similar error messages and there are several threads about this particular message on the Intel Support Forum. Make sure there is one and only one main program among the files you are compiling. If you are compiling object files without a main program, you must use the `-c` flag.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir for your patience. The above error message was due to the faulty name of the program file in the command. However, the problem is not solved yet. I am getting errors in spite of using the link line advisor generated command, which is stated below.

Comment: ifort -I-I${MKLROOT}/include/ia32/ -I"${MKLROOT}/include" iDFT_grafted.f90  ${MKLROOT}/lib/ia32/libmkl_lapack95.a -Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/ia32/libmkl_intel.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/ia32/libmkl_sequential.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm -ldl

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: The error is /home/username/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.0.0/include/lapack.f90(21): error #6218: This statement is positioned incorrectly and/or has syntax errors.
MODULE F95_PRECISION
^
/home/username/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.0.0/include/lapack.f90(24): error #6785: This name does not match the unit name.   [F95_PRECISION]
END MODULE F95_PRECISION
There is a similar question in the intel mkl user forum but it was not much help. https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/Intel-Fortran-and-MKL-How-to-include-lapack-f90-and-mkl-fi/td-p/1097693

Comment: You are probably including the file incorrectly. But for basic using of those subroutines you do not need these modules at all. Do *not* select BLAS95 or LAPACK95 and do not include the module files.